# Hitman Pro scan results

Tags: windows-7, virus, anti-virus

I installed Hitman Pro (trial version) a while ago on the recommendation of someone on either this forum or the MalwareBytes forum when I was trying to remove the globasearch virus from my computer. I did eventually manage to get rid of that virus using Hitman Pro and a few other antivirus/ antimalware programs.

My trial version of Hitman Pro has now expired, and although it still performs the occasional scan, I am unable to use it to remove any threats it detects.

It has just popped up telling me that a scan has been completed, and that there are no threats, however it has listed a few things: 'babylon.xml', 3 things called 'claro', and two tracking cookies... it says that the recommended action for all of these is to delete them, but obviously I can't do this since my trial version has expired. I was just wondering if anyone knows of any other way I can get rid of them without purchasing a license for Hitman Pro? I don't really want to have to be paying for more than one antivirus/ antimalware program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search yielded:
[Babylon removal guide](http://forums.spybot.info/showthread.php?t=61869)
[Claro removal guide](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/claro-search-virus/)

There is lots of info online on removing these and similar problems.

Comment: The babylon toolbar was removed ages ago- when I removed the globasearch virus from my computer... I tried looking throught the 'programs and features' list to remove it that way as suggested in your link, but babylon does not appear in that list... any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe read the Babylon removal guide. It might not be active on you computer anymore but there are some bits and pieces left over. You can delete those pieces manually without any problems.

Comment: Brilliant, cheers.

Comment: I've tried using Spybot, and it has removed some threats (Babylon included), however, it has also picked up a few things titled HKUS and an HKLM, as well as browser cache and browser cookie... but I don't seem to be able to select these in order to click remove- any idea why this would be?